# Multithreading in perl program giving unexpected result on windows

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am new to perl and trying out multithreading. I was expecting following program to create all the threads and print "created all the threads" at least after 5 seconds, once executed and all the threads waiting for the input value.

```
use threads;

my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
foreach (@arr) {
    sleep(1);
    print "\ncreating...\n";
    threads->new(\&echo, $_);
    print "\ncreated\n";
}
print "\ncreated all the threads\n";
sleep(200); #wait for the threads to finish

sub echo {
    my ($thread) = @_;
    print "\nthread($thread) Enter the value:\n";
    my $value = <>;
    print "\nthread($thread) Got value= $value\n";
}
```

But I am getting following outout:

```
creating...

created

thread(1) Enter the value:

creating...
```

It seems the other 3 threads are not yet created, if I remove the sleep(1) I get sometimes expected result, but with the sleep(1) involved, even waiting for few minutes, I get the above result. What I may be missing? I think it is something basic, but I am not able to figure out.

UPDATE:

The same program works on Linux flawless, what could be the platform specific problem for windows?

UPDATE2:

Following java program on the same lines works just fine on the same box:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class MT {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            new Thread(new Task(i)).start();
        }
        System.out.println("created all the threads");
        Thread.sleep(20000);

    }

    static class Task implements Runnable{

        int i;
        public Task(int i) {
            super();
            this.i = i;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread:"+i+" Enter value");
                int x= System.in.read();
                System.out.println(x);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how perl supports multithreading on windows!

Comment: Interesting. Your code works fine for me (v5.12.4 on Linux). What OS are you running it on?

Comment: Same here: Perl 5.14.2 on FreeBSD 8.3 and it works like a charm. Then same question: what OS are you on ? some Windows ?

Comment: This is Deja Vu, many times when I ask some question about perl problem, first comment is 'it works on my Linux box, what OS you using?' :) , I was assuming perl to be platform independent. Anyways I am running this on windows 2008 box with strawberry perl 5, version 16, subversion 0 (v5.16.0) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread.

Comment: indeed! it worked flawless on my Linux box as well! Sometime back I had got the same problem with ipv6 support, not working on windows but flawless on Linux.

Comment: My guess: is that Windows puts the entire *process* into a blocked-on-read state. Which is why you get at least one more time around when you remove the sleep in the main loop (I got 2).

Comment: With your original script - can you add the following at the top and re-run it? $| =1 ;  This will ensure your output is not buffering, which could give a misleading output.

Comment: @Disco no luck :( It seems to be the platform specific issue only as Axeman suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two different blocking issues:

1. I/O buffering on the console (thanks Disco 3 for suggesting this).
2. Threads reading from standard input block each other (but not other threads).

Consider this test program:

```
use threads;
 $| = 1;

my $thr1 = threads->new(\&echo, 1);
my $thr2 = threads->new(\&print_dots, 2);
sleep 10;
my $thr3 = threads->new(\&echo, 3);

sleep 200;



sub print_dots {
    while (1) {
        print ".";
        sleep 1;
    }
}

sub echo {

    my ($thread) = @_;
    print "\nthread($thread) Enter the value:\n";
    sleep 1;
    my $value = <>;
    print "\nthread($thread) Got value= $value\n";
}
```

If you do not disable i/o buffering (done by `$|=1;`), then you don't get any dots at all.  If you disable input buffering, the thread that prints dots is never blocked.  However, the second thread that reads from the console is still blocked by the first one.

If you need a true non-blocking read from standard input in Perl on Windows, there are a few potential solutions.   [`Win32::Console`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Console-0.09/Console.pm) is probably a good place to start. [Here is a potentially useful discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=720675).

Comment: Actually the problem originated from a networking code(a test case) where I wanted to start 2 sockets listening on some port and in 2 different threads and a client connecting them from the main thread. Better I use non-blocking sockets and maybe 'select', but then this really defeats one purpose of multi-threading i.e. the process shouldn't get blocked even if one of it's threads gets blocked in some operation; so that other threads can continue with other work, better to context switch between threads than processes.

Comment: @Sushant, the blocking issues may be more specific to the type of operation you are doing, rather than threading in general.  I believe that both sockets and console i/o have blocking issues on Win32, but they may not be the same.  You may need to ask a socket-specific question to get help with your problem.